# Queues and configuration switcher in Laravel

Tags: laravel, redis, laravel-queue

I got stucked with following thing: we have application which using some email service to send email. We targeted to have several of such services and be able to switch their configurations from web interface.

After some time switcher is working using module that rewriting config file (`config/mail.php` in particular) and `AppServiceProvider` with realization switcher based on what being written in that configuration file.

Mail sending being done using queues (on Redis).

The problem which I faced is that if I put `QUEUE_DRIVER=sync` into `.env` everything working as expected but if I leave `QUEUE_DRIVER=redis`as it is nothing happened like it using some old code or something else.

I tried restarting `supervisor`, `nginx`, redis, cleaning cache - no result.

Could anyone advice what is wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you check also logs ? nothings ?

Comment: Yes, empty :( That is weird

Comment: Try to put supervisor away for a moment, run redis, execute `php artisan queue:listen` and put some job on queue...

Comment: You where right @Goms issue was in supervisor afterall